# How to call side dish correctly?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar

The question that I have is how to describe a side dish for my main meal. The options that I have in mind:

1. I had a steak with fries as a side dish.
2. I had a steak with some fries on the side.
3. I had a steak with fries side dish.

Of course, it might happen that all these options are incorrect. I would like to know what the most common expression is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common forms:

- X with a side of Y
- X and a side of Y
- X with Y
- X and Y

The latter two can only be used when Y is known to always be a side dish, such as fries. Never use them when they could be misinterpreted as a compound main dish.